# Dockerize React application with docker-compose

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file which contains my project containers.

```
version: '3'
services:
   nginx:
      image: nginx
      ports:
          - "80:80"
          - "8080:8080"
      restart: always
      volumes:
          - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
      networks:
          - cw_network
      container_name: cw_proxy
      depends_on:
          - "db"
          - "api"
          - "web"
          - "vault"
   web:
      image: cw_web
      networks:
          - cw_network
      restart: always
      expose:
           - "9000"
      volumes:
          - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
          - ~/cw-front/:/var/www/html
          - ~/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      container_name: cw_web
   vault:
      image: cw_vault
      networks:
          - cw_network
      restart: always
      expose:
           - "9000"
      volumes:
          - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
          - ~/cw-vault/:/var/www/html
          - ~/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      container_name: cw_vault
      depends_on:
          - "api"
   db:
      image: postgres
      ports:
         - 5432:5432
      environment:
         POSTGRES_USER: 'user'
         POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'pass'
      volumes:
         - cw_sql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      networks:
         - cw_network
      container_name: cw_sql
   api:
      image: cw_api
      container_name: cw_api
      restart: always
      volumes:
        - ~/cw_api:/usr/src/cw_api
      ports:
       - "3001:3001"
      depends_on:
        - "db"
      networks:
        - cw_network
      entrypoint: ./wait-for-database.sh db 5432
      command: nodemon bin/www.js

volumes:
  cw_sql:
    external:
      name: cw_sql

networks:
  cw_network:
    external:
      name: cw_network
```

This is the `default.conf` for nginx to run web and vault

```
client_max_body_size 100m;

server {
    listen  80;
    server_name  localhost;
    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    # Add stdout logging
    error_log /dev/stdout info;
    access_log /dev/stdout;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass web:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}

server {
    listen  8080;
    server_name  localhost;
    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    # Add stdout logging
    error_log /dev/stdout info;
    access_log /dev/stdout;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass vault:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Let's suppose that I've implemented an SPA with ReactJs. I want to add this application to docker-compose. So, I made this Dockerfile

```
FROM node:9.11

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Copy all local files into the image.
COPY . .

# Install all dependencies of the current project.
COPY package.json package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g react-scripts

RUN npm run build
```

Because I have `react-router` installed I have to connect my react application with nginx. So, I append my `default.conf` file to accept the calls from port 3000.

```
    server {
        listen  3000;
        default_type application/octet-stream;
        root /var/www/html/build;

        gzip on;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
        gzip_min_length   256;
        gzip_vary         on;
        gzip_proxied      expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
        gzip_comp_level   9;

        location / {
          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }
    }
```

Also, I added port 3000 to nginx and added the service for the react app in `.yml` file

```
admin:
      image: cw_admin
      container_name: cw_admin
      restart: always
      volumes:
        - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
        - ~/admin_panel:/var/www/html
      depends_on:
        - "api"
      networks:
        - cw_network
```

But this didn't work. Actually the nginx throws 500 Server Error. Also the react container restarts itself and returns code 0.

What's the correct way to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing many things...First of all, I run `npm run build` before I create my image, and in my image, I had to serve my artifact. And secondly, the `default.conf` had a few errors.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:9.11

MAINTAINER Vassilis Pallas <vspallas@gmail.com>

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Install all dependencies of the current project.
COPY package.json package.json
RUN npm install

# Copy all local files into the image.
COPY . .

RUN npm install -g react-scripts
RUN npm install -g serve

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 5000

CMD serve -s build
```

docker-compose.yml

```
...
   admin:
      image: cw_admin
      container_name: cw_admin
      restart: unless-stopped
      ports:
       - "5000:5000"
      expose:
        - "5000"
      volumes:
        - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
        - ~/admin_panel:/var/www/html
      depends_on:
        - "api"
      networks:
        - cw_network
```

default.conf

```
...
server {
    listen  5000;
    server_name  localhost;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    root /var/www/html/build;

    gzip on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_min_length   256;
    gzip_vary         on;
    gzip_proxied      expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    gzip_comp_level   9;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://admin:5000;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your Dockerfile you are copying all the files, then the package.json, then installing and finally building. 

This of course works but it isn't the best approach. You should first copy package.json, install the dependencies, then copy the app, and finally build. This way you are not reinstalling all the dependencies each time you make a change in the app.